# how can I get count of record in mongodb

Tags: sql, mongodb, count

I am new in mongodb and stuck while getting count of records
SQL Query -> **select count(receipt_no) from complaints**
i want the same query in mongodb.
Please help me
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Mongo DB is NoSQL DB. This means it contains unstructured data, not in the form of rows and columns exactly. But yes there are ways to use all these functions.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/
Here is a link for MongoDB usage.

```
db.collection.find( {} ).count()
```

it gets all the data and counts it. these empty curly braces are used to specify some conditions if any in finding data.

Answer (score 1):

`db.getCollection("complaints").find({ receipt_no: { $exists: true }}).count()`

The above will count all the documents in the `complaints` collection that have the `receipt_no` field present.